# Java Icon label

Tags: java, image, swing, pdf

My question is how to save an Icon image to a variable in Java?

When all the values are displayed from my SQL database in the `JTextfields`, I can write them on a PDF file in Java. However, I retrieve an image from my database which appears on a `JLabel`.

How do I get that image to appear on my pdf file in Java?

Note that all my details in my `JTextfields` are shown in the PDF file when it is created.

I want this image to appear in my PDF file.

[image: image to embed in pdf]

```
String val8 = id.getText();
Icon val11 = lblimg.getIcon();  

try{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Report.pdf"));
    doc.open();

    doc.add(new Paragraph("Employee Information", 
        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,18, Font.BOLD, 
        BaseColor.RED)));
    doc.add(new Paragraph(
        "______________________________________________________________________________"));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Employee ID is " + val));
```

Comment: Is the image itself relevant to the question?

Comment: Yes it is.. so that you can know what is happening